# Can't create Foreign Key in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables: `SDCUST` and the newly created `SDRTS` (defined below).

SDCUST table definition

[image]

```
DROP TABLE SDRTS
  GO
  CREATE TABLE SDRTS(
    BGTID int NOT NULL,
    RTSID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_SDRTS PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (BGTID,RTSID),
    CUSTID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_SDRTS_SDCUST FOREIGN KEY(CUSTID)
    REFERENCES SDRTS(CUSTID),
    BGRPID_1 uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    BGRPID_2 uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    INCRT FLOAT NULL,
    CURRID int NOT NULL,
    EDATE datetime NULL,
    EUSRID uniqueidentifier NULL,
    UDATE datetime NULL,
    UUSRID uniqueidentifier NULL,
    V001 float NULL,
```

I want `CUSTID` to be the foreign key on the new table, but I get an error:

> Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 1
>   Cannot drop the table 'SDRTS', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
>   Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
>   There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'SDRTS' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_SDRTS_SDCUST'.
>   Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

How can I create this key?

Comment: You are referencing the same table. `REFERENCES SDRTS(CUSTID)` You need to reference the `SDCUST` table instead.

Comment: CONSTRAINT FK_SDRTS_SDCUST FOREIGN KEY(CUSTID)
 REFERENCES SDCUST(CUSTID),     but error message: Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 1
Cannot drop the table 'SDRTS', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'SDCUST' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_SDRTS_SDCUST'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: Hmm. Can you show the schema for the `SDCUST` table. Also, put an `IF Exists` before your drop statement to remove the first error.

Comment: @WEI_DBA of course, ı added as a picture, table design.

Comment: Is `BGTID` on `SDRTS` table the same as on the `SDCUST` table?

Comment: You cannot reference part of a PK. You need to reference all of the PK.

Comment: Same but in the SDRTS table Not Null @WEI_DBA 
If you are, will you be with Teamviewer?

Comment: CONSTRAINT FK_SDRTS_SDCUST FOREIGN KEY(CUSTID) REFERENCES SDCUST(CUSTID),   There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'SDCUST' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_SDRTS_SDCUST'.

Comment: Add both columns. `CONSTRAINT FK_SDRTS_SDCUST FOREIGN KEY(BGTID, CUSTID) REFERENCES SDCUST(BGTID, CUSTID)`

Comment: okey, successful
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on the comments this was resolved by:

Add both columns. `CONSTRAINT FK_SDRTS_SDCUST FOREIGN KEY(BGTID, CUSTID) REFERENCES SDCUST(BGTID, CUSTID)`